# Meteor: Security in Templates and Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm enjoying working with Meteor and trying out new things, but I often try to keep security in mind. So while I'm building out a prototype app, I'm trying to find the best practices for keeping the app secure. One thing I keep coming across is restricting a user based on either a roll, or whether or not they're logged in. Here are two examples of issues I'm having.

```
// First example, trying to only fire an event if the user is an admin
// This is using the alaning:roles package
Template.homeIndex.events({
  "click .someclass": function(event) {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin', 'admin-group') {
      // Do something only if an admin in admin-group
    }
});
```

My problem with the above is I can override this by typing:
`Roles.userIsInRole = function() { return true; }` in this console. Ouch.

The second example is using Iron Router. Here I want to allow a user to the "/chat" route only if they're logged in.

```
Router.route("/chat", {
  name: 'chatHome',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    // Not secure! Meteor.user = function() { return true; } in the console.
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
      return this.redirect('homeIndex');
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
 },
 waitOn: function () {
    if (!!Meteor.user()) {
      return Meteor.subscribe("messages");
    }
 },
 data: function () {
   return {
      chatActive: true
   }
 }
});
```

Again I run into the same problem. `Meteor.user = function() { return true; }` in this console blows this pattern up. The only way around this I have found thus far is using a Meteor.method call, which seems improper, as they are stubs that require callbacks.

What is the proper way to address this issue?

Edit:

Using a Meteor.call callback doesn't work for me since it's calling for a response asynchronously. It's moving out of the hook before it can handle the response.

```
onBeforeAction: function() {
  var self = this;
  Meteor.call('someBooleanFunc', function(err, res) {
    if (!res) {
      return self.redirect('homeIndex');
    } else {
      self.next();
    }
  })
},
```

Comment: You have it right - anything that would require a authentication should be done with **trusted code** on the server. Anything on the client is **untrusted**. `Meteor.call` is how you can access that server code from the client.

Comment: @Matt, I've edited the question to include an example of the Meteor.call I was making that also wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should try adding a check in the publish method in server. 
Something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('messages') {


        if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin', 'admin-group')) {
            return Meteor.messages.find();
        }
        else {
            // user not authorized. do not publish messages
            this.stop();
            return;
          }

    });
```

You may do a similar check in your call methods in server.

Comment: This is an additional security check, which is fine, but it shouldn't be necessary. The template will still load, just without data.

Comment: http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-iron-router-filters-before-and-after-hooks. This site was helpful to me when working with iron-router. Instead of adding onBeforeAction check for every route calls, I created a global Iron Router check using "Router.before". So when the user is not logged in, it would be redirected to given route. I am not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Not exactly, but thank you for the resources and help. Sadly, he also does checks is his examples within the Routers and Router.before using Meteor.user() on the client-side. This can also be overridden by the client with `Meteor.user = function() { return true; }` in a console.

Comment: Well, suppose a malicious user gets to /chat using the above function. If the data therein is based on a subscription, he won't get any data to populate the template if you check for userid in `publish`

Comment: Right, and that's fine, but shouldn't be the solution in this case. If it were a route with no data, we wouldn't want to do a publish and if there were some static information on the restricted page, they would also see that.